# Is $\mathbb{Q}( 5^{1/3},\sqrt{7})/\mathbb{Q}$ a normal extension?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Can someone give me a working out of this please. I don't really have any detailed examples in my notes so i have no idea about this normal extension stuff.

I do know that an extension $K\subseteq L$ is normal if whenever $g \in K[x]$ is irreducible and has at least one root in $L$, then $g$ splits completely in $L$.

A polynomial that is in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ and will have the roots of $5^{1/3}$ and $\sqrt7$ is $(x^3-5)(x^2-7)$ but its hard to say if this is irreducible.

I just need to see a detailed working of these normal extension questions and then i think i might be able to do them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The polynomial $f(x)=x^3-5$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ by Eisenstein's criterion, and has a root $5^{\frac{1}{3}}$ in $K=\mathbb{Q}(5^{\frac{1}{3}},\sqrt{7})$, but does not split in $K$ because the other roots of $f$ are non-real and $K$ is real. Therefore $K$ is not normal.

Comment: So the f you have does not have to have the same degree as [K:Q]? which is 6 i think...

Comment: That's right. For $K/\mathbb{Q}$ to be normal, every polynomial $g(x)\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ with a root in $K$ must split in $K$.

Comment: But say if it were normal, then how is it possible to check EVERY irreducible polynomial in Q that splits in Q?

Comment: In practice that's not the way to go. But if you know that $K$ is the splitting field of an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$, then it will be normal.

Comment: OK so if we wanted to see if  $Q( 5^{1/4},√11,i)/Q$ is normal, how can we do it? I feel like it is normal because of that imaginary.

Comment: That's worth making a separate question for, as the argument will be different.